# Normal subgroups of GL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ and SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I wants to compute all the normal subgroups of SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$. Please give me some idea or reference to study about this. I have seen following question and answer given for $n=2$ but I just not neede the statement I wants to go through proof as well ([Normal subgroups of the Special Linear Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225510/normal-subgroups-of-the-special-linear-group)).

Comment: The only proper nontrivial normal subgroup is $\{I_n,-I_n\}$. This follows from the well-knwn fact that ${\rm PSL}(n,{\mathbb R})$ is simple for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your answer, what can we say for GL$(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You have to be clear on what you mean by a normal subgroup:  a Lie subgroup or an arbitrary subgroup. The proof in the case of arbitrary  subgroups is much harder.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your comment sir, but I need the arbitrary subgroup, if proof is not easy then I will manage, but can you give the number of normal subgroups?

Comment: @DerekHolt sir, I think $\{I_3,-I_3\}$ is not a subgroup of SL$(3,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Yes that's true. But I don't think that I  said it was - I didn't say for all $n$. But  I suppose that what I wrote might have been misleading.

Comment: Ok sir, so I can conclude that SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ is simple for odd $n\geq 3?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be any field and $n \ge 2$ and let $G = {\rm GL}(n,K)$ and $S = {\rm SL}(n,K)$. Let's exclude the  two small exceptional cases $n=2$ and $|K| \le 3$.

Then $[G,G]=S$ with $S$ perfect, $Z(G)$ is the subgroup $Z$ of nonzero scalar matrices, and $S/(S \cap K) = {\rm PSL}(n,K)$ is simple.

It follows that, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$  with $N \not\le Z$, then $[G,N] = S$, so  $S \le N$.

So there are just two types of normal subgroups of $G$, those contained in $Z$, and those that contain $S$. Since $Z \cong G/S \cong (K \setminus \{0\},\times)$, the normal subgroups of both types correspond exactly to the subgroups of $(K \setminus \{0\},\times)$.